# Your Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, gemfile.lock

**What happened:**

- Initially I was trying to deploy this simple blog app to Heroku but ran into a merge conflict issue with my `Gemfile.lock` and now of course I can no longer run `rails s` too on my terminal.

**Error Message**

- The exact error I'm having is as follows:

> 

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
    5: from bin/rails:2:in `<main>'
    4: from bin/rails:2:in `load'
    3: from /Users/leatinoso/codes/blog_app/bin/spring:7:in `<top (required)>'
    2: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.8/lib/bundler.rb:210:in `locked_gems'
    1: from /Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.8/lib/bundler.rb:210:in `new'
/Users/leatinoso/.asdf/installs/ruby/2.7.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.7.0/gems/bundler-2.2.8/lib/bundler/lockfile_parser.rb:70:in `initialize': Your Gemfile.lock contains merge conflicts. (Bundler::LockfileError)
Run `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` first to get a clean lock.
```

**What was done so far**

1. Followed this Stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26454568/gemfile-lock-contains-merge-conflicts) and I'm still encountering the same error. In essence it's suggesting I run `git checkout HEAD -- Gemfile.lock` and `bundle install`.
2. I also reviewed this Github [post](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/issues/3198) and it's also suggesting the same thing.

**My Rails setup**

```
Rails 6.1.4
ruby 2.7.2p137 (2020-10-01 revision 5445e04352) [arm64-darwin20]
Node -v: v14.15.4
Yarn -v: 1.22.10
```

**Gemfile***

> 

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }

ruby '2.7.2'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails', branch: 'main'
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
<<<<<<< HEAD
# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
=======
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
gem 'pg'
# Use Puma as the app server
gem 'puma', '~> 5.0'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '>= 6'
# Transpile app-like JavaScript. Read more: https://github.com/rails/webpacker
gem 'webpacker', '~> 5.0'
# Turbolinks makes navigating your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/turbolinks/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.7'
# Use Redis adapter to run Action Cable in production
# gem 'redis', '~> 4.0'
# Use Active Model has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt', '~> 3.1.7'

# Use Active Storage variant
# gem 'image_processing', '~> 1.2'

# Reduces boot times through caching; required in config/boot.rb
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.4.4', require: false

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end

group :development do
  # Access an interactive console on exception pages or by calling 'console' anywhere in the code.
  gem 'web-console', '>= 4.1.0'
  # Display performance information such as SQL time and flame graphs for each request in your browser.
  # Can be configured to work on production as well see: https://github.com/MiniProfiler/rack-mini-profiler/blob/master/README.md
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler', '~> 2.0'
  gem 'listen', '~> 3.3'
  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======

  # Solargraph is a Ruby gem that provides intellisense features  
  gem 'solargraph'
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 3.26'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of web drivers to run system tests with browsers
  gem 'webdrivers'
end

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]
```

**Gemfile.lock**

> 

```
GEM
  remote: https://rubygems.org/
  specs:
    actioncable (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
      websocket-driver (>= 0.6.1)
    actionmailbox (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      mail (>= 2.7.1)
    actionmailer (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      mail (~> 2.5, >= 2.5.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
    actionpack (6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      rack (~> 2.0, >= 2.0.9)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.0, >= 1.2.0)
    actiontext (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      nokogiri (>= 1.8.5)
    actionview (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      builder (~> 3.1)
      erubi (~> 1.4)
      rails-dom-testing (~> 2.0)
      rails-html-sanitizer (~> 1.1, >= 1.2.0)
    activejob (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      globalid (>= 0.3.6)
    activemodel (6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
    activerecord (6.1.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
    activestorage (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      marcel (~> 1.0.0)
      mini_mime (>= 1.1.0)
    activesupport (6.1.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0, >= 1.0.2)
      i18n (>= 1.6, < 2)
      minitest (>= 5.1)
      tzinfo (~> 2.0)
      zeitwerk (~> 2.3)
    addressable (2.8.0)
      public_suffix (>= 2.0.2, < 5.0)
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    ast (2.4.2)
    backport (1.2.0)
    benchmark (0.1.0)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    bindex (0.8.1)
    bootsnap (1.7.5)
      msgpack (~> 1.0)
    builder (3.2.4)
    byebug (11.1.3)
    capybara (3.35.3)
      addressable
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.3)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
      rack (>= 1.6.0)
      rack-test (>= 0.6.3)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.5, < 3.0)
      xpath (~> 3.2)
    childprocess (3.0.0)
    concurrent-ruby (1.1.9)
    crass (1.0.6)
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    diff-lcs (1.4.4)
    e2mmap (0.1.0)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    erubi (1.10.0)
    ffi (1.15.3)
    globalid (0.4.2)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
    i18n (1.8.10)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
<<<<<<< HEAD
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
=======
    jaro_winkler (1.5.4)
    jbuilder (2.11.2)
      activesupport (>= 5.0.0)
    kramdown (2.3.1)
      rexml
    kramdown-parser-gfm (1.1.0)
      kramdown (~> 2.0)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    listen (3.5.1)
      rb-fsevent (~> 0.10, >= 0.10.3)
      rb-inotify (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.10)
    loofah (2.10.0)
      crass (~> 1.0.2)
      nokogiri (>= 1.5.9)
    mail (2.7.1)
      mini_mime (>= 0.1.1)
    marcel (1.0.1)
    method_source (1.0.0)
    mini_mime (1.1.0)
    mini_portile2 (2.5.3)
    minitest (5.14.4)
    msgpack (1.4.2)
    nio4r (2.5.7)
    nokogiri (1.11.7)
      mini_portile2 (~> 2.5.0)
      racc (~> 1.4)
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    parallel (1.20.1)
    parser (3.0.0.0)
      ast (~> 2.4.1)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    pg (1.2.3)
    public_suffix (4.0.6)
    puma (5.3.2)
      nio4r (~> 2.0)
    racc (1.5.2)
    rack (2.2.3)
    rack-mini-profiler (2.3.2)
      rack (>= 1.2.0)
    rack-proxy (0.7.0)
      rack
    rack-test (1.1.0)
      rack (>= 1.0, < 3)
    rails (6.1.4)
      actioncable (= 6.1.4)
      actionmailbox (= 6.1.4)
      actionmailer (= 6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      actiontext (= 6.1.4)
      actionview (= 6.1.4)
      activejob (= 6.1.4)
      activemodel (= 6.1.4)
      activerecord (= 6.1.4)
      activestorage (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      bundler (>= 1.15.0)
      railties (= 6.1.4)
      sprockets-rails (>= 2.0.0)
    rails-dom-testing (2.0.3)
      activesupport (>= 4.2.0)
      nokogiri (>= 1.6)
    rails-html-sanitizer (1.3.0)
      loofah (~> 2.3)
    railties (6.1.4)
      actionpack (= 6.1.4)
      activesupport (= 6.1.4)
      method_source
      rake (>= 0.13)
      thor (~> 1.0)
<<<<<<< HEAD
    rake (13.0.6)
=======
    rainbow (3.0.0)
    rake (13.0.5)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    rb-fsevent (0.11.0)
    rb-inotify (0.10.1)
      ffi (~> 1.0)
    regexp_parser (2.1.1)
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    reverse_markdown (2.0.0)
      nokogiri
    rexml (3.2.4)
    rubocop (0.90.0)
      parallel (~> 1.10)
      parser (>= 2.7.1.1)
      rainbow (>= 2.2.2, < 4.0)
      regexp_parser (>= 1.7)
      rexml
      rubocop-ast (>= 0.3.0, < 1.0)
      ruby-progressbar (~> 1.7)
      unicode-display_width (>= 1.4.0, < 2.0)
    rubocop-ast (0.8.0)
      parser (>= 2.7.1.5)
    ruby-progressbar (1.11.0)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    rubyzip (2.3.2)
    sass-rails (6.0.0)
      sassc-rails (~> 2.1, >= 2.1.1)
    sassc (2.4.0)
      ffi (~> 1.9)
    sassc-rails (2.1.2)
      railties (>= 4.0.0)
      sassc (>= 2.0)
      sprockets (> 3.0)
      sprockets-rails
      tilt
    selenium-webdriver (3.142.7)
      childprocess (>= 0.5, < 4.0)
      rubyzip (>= 1.2.2)
    semantic_range (3.0.0)
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    solargraph (0.42.4)
      backport (~> 1.2)
      benchmark
      bundler (>= 1.17.2)
      diff-lcs (~> 1.4)
      e2mmap
      jaro_winkler (~> 1.5)
      kramdown (~> 2.3)
      kramdown-parser-gfm (~> 1.1)
      parser (~> 3.0)
      reverse_markdown (>= 1.0.5, < 3)
      rubocop (>= 0.52)
      thor (~> 1.0)
      tilt (~> 2.0)
      yard (~> 0.9, >= 0.9.24)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    spring (2.1.1)
    sprockets (4.0.2)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
      rack (> 1, < 3)
    sprockets-rails (3.2.2)
      actionpack (>= 4.0)
      activesupport (>= 4.0)
      sprockets (>= 3.0.0)
    thor (1.1.0)
    tilt (2.0.10)
    turbolinks (5.2.1)
      turbolinks-source (~> 5.2)
    turbolinks-source (5.2.0)
    tzinfo (2.0.4)
      concurrent-ruby (~> 1.0)
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    unicode-display_width (1.7.0)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    web-console (4.1.0)
      actionview (>= 6.0.0)
      activemodel (>= 6.0.0)
      bindex (>= 0.4.0)
      railties (>= 6.0.0)
    webdrivers (4.6.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.6)
      rubyzip (>= 1.3.0)
      selenium-webdriver (>= 3.0, < 4.0)
    webpacker (5.4.0)
      activesupport (>= 5.2)
      rack-proxy (>= 0.6.1)
      railties (>= 5.2)
      semantic_range (>= 2.3.0)
    websocket-driver (0.7.5)
      websocket-extensions (>= 0.1.0)
    websocket-extensions (0.1.5)
    xpath (3.2.0)
      nokogiri (~> 1.8)
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
    yard (0.9.26)
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
    zeitwerk (2.4.2)

PLATFORMS
  ruby

DEPENDENCIES
  bootsnap (>= 1.4.4)
  byebug
  capybara (>= 3.26)
  jbuilder (~> 2.7)
  listen (~> 3.3)
  pg
  puma (~> 5.0)
  rack-mini-profiler (~> 2.0)
  rails (~> 6.1.4)
  sass-rails (>= 6)
  selenium-webdriver
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======
  solargraph
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
  spring
  turbolinks (~> 5)
  tzinfo-data
  web-console (>= 4.1.0)
  webdrivers
  webpacker (~> 5.0)

RUBY VERSION
   ruby 2.7.2p137

BUNDLED WITH
   2.2.8
```

Answer (score 2):

Your have merge conflicts in both your Gemfile and Gemfile.lock. You can't generate a new Gemfile.lock from a Gemfile with merge conflicts.

First, remove the merge conflicts in the Gemfile.

```rb
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
<<<<<<< HEAD
# Use postgres as the database for Active Record
=======
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
```

Could become:

```rb
gem 'rails', '~> 6.1.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
```

And:

```rb
<<<<<<< HEAD
=======

  # Solargraph is a Ruby gem that provides intellisense features  
  gem 'solargraph'
>>>>>>> 83d186c9a3ca227a4c1aea18936043ded82ceb2e
```

Could become:

```rb
  # Solargraph is a Ruby gem that provides intellisense features  
  gem 'solargraph'
```

Keep or remove solargraph as you see fit.

Then, regenerate the lockfile. I might start with a new lockfile.

```
$ rm Gemfile.lock
$ bundle install
```

Alternatively, check out the lockfile from a commit where it doesn't have merge conflicts, and then run `bundle install` to update it.

Comment: This did the trick on my gemfile. Essentially I did the same thing on the rest of my files which had merge conflicts. Also, I ran `$ grep -lr '<<<<<<< HEAD' .` which listed the rest of the files which had issues then I clicked "Accept incoming changes" on all those file. Thanks for this! Gave me a good headstart.